# ruby on rails button_to delete method not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, destroy

**view:**

```
<%= button_to 'Delete Friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), method: 'delete', :form_class => 'delete_btn', remote: true %>
```

**controller:**

```
def destroy
   @return = 'It works!'
   render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )
end
```

when i click the button i get a **404 page not found**... how can i make the **destroy method** work for **ajax jquery requests**?

EDIT:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :friendships, :except => [:new, :edit, :update, :index, :show]
```

running `rake:routes`

```
                 friendships POST   /friendships(.:format)                          friendships#create
                  friendship DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)                      friendships#destroy
```

Comment: `friendships_path` doesn't respect REST, what do you have in your routes?

Comment: @apneadiving i have updated the questions with the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
friendships_path(:friend_id => @user)
```

With:

```
friendship_path(:id => @user)
```